# CSS DIV width based on text length with position absolute relative to a TABLE cell

Tags: css, flexbox

Brief introduction:
with my attempts I have reached an acceptable result

to a specific table cell I set inline the (in the screenshots below it is the third last TH)

`<th style="position:relative;">Column Name</th>`

then inside the cell I have positioned my DIV

`<th style="position:relative;"><div id="myDiv" style="position:relative;">Line 1 - medium length<br>Line2 - John</div></th>`

EDIT: as requested I post the significant code

the DIV CSS

```
#provDiv{  /** the DIV CSS */
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    width: auto;  
    background: greenyellow;  
    text-align: right;
  }
```

the involved cell,

```
<th data-dbrow="device" scope="col" 
style="position:relative; width: 10%">
    <div id="provDiv">Line 1 - medium length<br>Line 2 - John</div>
</th>
```

What it happen is that (I'd say "obviously") the DIV long text will wrap, because the DIV will have as maximum width -> the table column's width, this using `width: auto;`

while if I set `width: 300px` the DIV width is really 300px

with fixed width, I have the DIV larger than the column width,

but then the div is ALWAYS large 300px, despite the content,

so if DIV innerText is just 5 chars like "hello", I have a laaaaarge DIV quite awful to see.

Well the question is:
how to have the DIV WIDTH that adapts to the text line length, without using a fixed width?

- please note that I must use bootstrap 5
- if it can help in this case, I'm available to use flexbox, but I haven't studied it yet

These are my tests

1. current result with auto and two text lines long text

[image: current result with auto and two text lines long text]

2. worse result with fixed width and short text

[image]

3. 1th wanted result

[image: wanted result]

4. 2nd wanted result

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `max-width` instead?

Comment: Can you post the  code please?

Comment: @skobaljic :-) because with max-width the text long text wraps

Comment: Try `width: fit-content` with `padding: 0 10px` for extra space on the `right` and the `left` of the `div`

Comment: @001 tried that one too fit-content + padding, still wrapping. Nice challenge , isn't it? :) Now you have the code above in the post

Comment: @001 right below the two snippets I have added a link to the full HTML page code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `classes` = `parent`, `myDiv`. This is a mix of using `table` and `flexbox layout`

```css
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 35px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}


/* Check the styles below*/
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.myDiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="parent">
          Company
            <div class="myDiv">Hello World</div>
          </th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
          <td>Christina Berglund</td>
          <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And you can hide large text and show dots instead if the `width` of `myDiv` is more than `300px`:

```
.myDiv {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-width: 300px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### EDIT: Solution for your code

Check:

```
#provDiv{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: greenyellow;  
    text-align: right;
    /*ADDED*/
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 300px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
      #provDiv{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        width: fit-content;
        padding: 0 5px;
        background: greenyellow;  
        text-align: right;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden; 
        max-width: 300px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    </style>

    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
              <h1 class="p-1">Calls</h1>
              <p id="provincie"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-end">
              <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" id="AggiungiRiga" type="submit" value="Submit" >+ Riga</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger m-3" id="EliminaRiga" type="submit" value="Submit" >- Riga</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button class="btn btn-success m-3" id="SalvaRiga" type="submit" value="Submit" >Salva</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table style="min-width:1000px;" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered text-center" id="tabella">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-dbrow="riga" scope="col" style="width: 5%">#</th>
              <th data-dbrow="id" scope="col" style="width: 5%">ID</th>
              <th data-dbrow="nome" scope="col" style="width: 30%">Nome</th>
              <th data-dbrow="tel" scope="col" style="width: 11%">Telefono</th>
              <th data-dbrow="mail" scope="col" style="width: 29%">Email</th>
              <th data-dbrow="device" scope="col" style="position:relative; width: 10%">
                  <select id="select1" class="form-select form-select-sm">
                      <option value="$" selected disabled>- Text 1 -</option>
                      <option value="val1">Text 2</option>
                      <option value="val2">Text 3</option>
                      <option value="val2">Text 4</option>
                  </select>
                  <div id="provDiv">Line 1 - medium length<br>Line 2 - John</div>
              </th>
              <th data-dbrow="iscli" scope="col" style="width: 5%">&Egrave; Cli</th>
              <th data-dbrow="prov" scope="col" class="cellaProv" style="width: 5%">Prov</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="table1bd">

              <tr>
                <th>some text</th>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>            
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>            
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>some text</th>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>            
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>            
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>some text</th>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>            
                <td contenteditable="true">some text</td>            
              </tr>                            

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>  

    </div>

    

    <pre></pre>

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried your CSS inside bootstrap and text lines are wrapped. I have two lines of text and they may become up to five lines. Now at top, right below the two snippets in my question, I have linked the full page HTML code, can you kindly replace your code with that one? Since and because I use bootstrap 5 and I must use it

Comment: Check **EDIT Section** please

Comment: Cool! What is the combination that does the trick? Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Basically, I just added `width: fit-content`, and `max-width: 300px`, so it will expand till `300px width`. and we prevent the text from `wrapping` by hiding it and adding dots *...* if it's length is expanding more `300px`

Comment: And please if you found this answer is helpful, voting will be appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you. I have approved the reply. Please one kind favor, just edit the select list placing dummy items instead than my real ones, thank you

Comment: You mean the `option`s? *HDD*, *Chiavetta*, etc...?

Comment: Yes, them. Thank you. Replace with Item 1 , item 2 , item 3 will be fine

Comment: Sure, done... You can check the code above.

Comment: for the sake of letting know. This div does contain the result of a live AJAX search, so I type in the column 'Prov' (Province) and in the DIV I get the list of corresponding provinces